# Using sklearn.model_selection to split unbalanced dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I am using the following code to split my dataset into train/val/test sets.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
        train_test_split(X_data, y_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val = 
        train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
```

The problem is that my dataset is really unbalanced. Some classes have 500 samples while some have 70 for example. Is this splitting method accurate in this situation? Is the sampling random or does sklearn use seome methods to keep the distribution of the data same in all sets?

Comment: Why do you split the test data twice? You'll get a test data size of 15% like this?

Comment: @Scotty1 The intention is to get train set (70%), val set (15%) and test set (15%)

Comment: It would be a great if you can update the question with "Unbalanced Dataset". It would be helpful to others in future.

Comment: @Aditya Kansal Did it

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: It was, but I usually keep my questions unanswered for a little in case someone else has also something to say.

Comment: OK, doesn't sound like a bad practice... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `stratify` option (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
        train_test_split(X_data, y_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=y_data)

X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val = 
        train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, stratify=y_test)
```